# Run node.js with different file extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-extension

Is is possible to run node.js with a different extension than `.js` like: `node server.type` instead of `node server.js`?

I have tried [require.extensions](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions)

```
require.extensions['.type'] = require.extensions['.js'];
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: /root/project/server.type: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

However I think this has nothing to do with `require` unless I want to require these files from within node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works just fine:

```
$ echo 'console.log("hello world")' > server.type
$ node server.type
hello world
```

But I'm guessing that you want to run it as an executable. In that case, start your script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

# followed by your actual script:
console.log("hello world");
```

And make your script executable:

```
chmod 755 server.type
```

After that:

```
$ /root/project/server.type
hello world
```